# Have a List of Arrays in Java; How to Sort By the Last Element of Each Array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

I have a snippet of code which looks as follows:

```
List<int[]> v1v2weighting = new ArrayList<int[]>();

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        int[] a = {i,j,graph[i][j]};
        v1v2weighting.add(a);
    }
}
```

After this concludes, I have a list of 3-element arrays, where the final element in each array is the weighting. I'd now like to sort this list by the weighting, ie arrive at a finished list where for every element e, e_i[2] ≤ e_(i+1)[2]. Is there a simple way to perform an operation like this in Java? I've come across collections.sort() while looking for a solution, but this seems to only work in the event that I'm dealing with a list of comparables such as integers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `v1v2weighting.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[2]));`

Comment: When I try to implement this I receive "error: illegal start of expression" with the arrow -> being indicated as the problem

Comment: @MMMMMCK which Java version ?

Comment: Yeah, that bug was fixed in Java 8.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik  1.7.0_151 is displayed in the terminal

Comment: @shmosel that's not bug, but `->` is a new syntax introduced in Java 8.

Comment: @Alex Really? Hmm, well that explains a lot...

Answer (score 1):

For sorting `List` in Java 1.7, you may use the following code segment.

```
Collections.sort(v1v2weighting, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1[2], o2[2]); // suppose all your arrays has at least 3 elements
    }
}
```

In fact, you may implement any sorting mechanism using this method.

Comment: Safer to use `Integer.compare()`, since subtraction can underflow.

Comment: @shmosel good suggestion, and I modified the answer with your comment.